# Delete rows in SAS data set where all other values are missing except one column

Tags: sas, missing-data

I have a SAS data set say, `df` like this:

```
Input:
A B C D
1 . . .
2 . . .
3 0 1 1
4 1 0 1
```

Code for data-creation:

```
data df;
  input A B C D;
  DATALINES;
1 . . .
2 . . .
3 0 1 1
4 1 0 1
;
run;
```

Now I want to delete the 1st 2 rows. The logic I need is to delete those rows in `df` where all values are missing in a row except in `A`.

```
Output:
A B C D
3 0 1 1
4 1 0 1
```

I am very new to SAS and I request an answer without `proc sql`.

> Note: Here I gave only 4 columns. Actually I have more than 25 columns.I need a generalized answer without using column names B,C,D

Comment: there can be different columns with missing values in each row?

Comment: No, my requirement is, I always have a value in A. Only B to D will have missing values always.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `CMISS()` function on both numeric and character variables. But you will need to know how many variables there are.

```
data have;
  input A B C $ D;
cards;
1 . . .
2 . . .
3 0 1 1
4 1 0 1
;

data want;
  set have;
  if cmiss(of B--D)<3 ;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Put all relevant variables in an array and count the number of NON missing values. Output all rows with one or more non-missing values.

```
data want;
    set df;
    array varlist B -- D;
    do over varlist;
        not_missing = sum(not_missing, ^missing(varlist));
    end;
    if not_missing > 0 and ^missing(A) then output;
run;
```

Comment: The logic fails if I have a non missing value in B or C or D in 1st 2 rows and missing A. I mean if A is null and B is not null in 1st row, it stil goes as output.

Comment: Could you give a data example in your questions? Do you want to check for missings in A or not? I will change my answer to separately checking A.

Answer (score 1):

If all the variables are numeric then the `n` function will work as this counts the number of non-missing values.

```
data have;
Input A B C D;
datalines;
1 . . .
2 . . .
3 0 1 1
4 1 0 1
;
run;

data have;
modify have;
if n(of B--D)=0 then remove;
run;
```

Comment: The logic is good for numeric Columns, but I have character columns too

Comment: Use CMISS() function instead, but you will need to know how many variables there are. `if cmiss(of b--d) <3;`

Comment: @Tom Exactly what I was about to put.  Except it should say =3, not <3

Comment: Depends on what statement you using the expression in.  Subsetting if: `IF CMISS(of B--D) <3;`  Or IF/THEN : `IF CMISS(OF B--D)=3 THEN DELETE;` or `IF CMISS(of B--D)<3 THEN OUTPUT;`

Answer (score 0):

```
data result;
   set df;
   where ^missing(B) and ^missing(C) and ^missing(D);
run;
```

or

```
proc sql noprint;
   create table result as
   select *
   from df
   where ^missing(B) and ^missing(C) and ^missing(D);
quit;
```

> EDIT:

```
proc contents data=df out=df_CONTENTS; run;
proc sql noprint;
   select cats('^missing(',NAME,')') into :var_names separated by ' and '
   from df_CONTENTS
   where NAME ^= 'A';
quit;
```

and then you can use value 'var_names' for condition in where clause as:

> `where &var_names;`

Comment: Sorry Andrey, I forgot to mention the Note earlier. Updated Note. Anyways thanks for the response.